# Copying MySql tables to Sqlite with java

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite

I need to have few tables contained in a MySql db transferred to an Sqlite database through Java code.

For this, in my application, I do the following:

1. create an Sqlite db
2. select * from each table(of mysql db) , fetch data corresponding to each field from resultset, and insert data of each field to the corresponding sqlite table.

Is this the correct approach? Are there better methods of doing this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to create the schema in the SQLite also with java?

Comment: Do you really want to do it with Java? or other solution is accepted?

Answer (score 2):

Export the schema from MySQL **with insert scripts**, edit it (remove the MySQL-specific syntax), then execute it in SQLite.

Comment: I am doing just that only. I was asking is this the correct approach since there are numerous read and insertions happening.

Comment: Ocassionally you can add manually a `commit;` for every 1000 rows to reduce the transaction overhead.

Comment: Any result? Was it successful?

Answer (score 2):

If this is something that only happens once, you might consider using sqlite .import command (http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) and using mysqldump to dump the data into a csv file that can be read by .import

Answer (score 1):

Look at this python approach. may this can help you

https://gist.github.com/2972461